# Toggle Multiple Drop Down Menus in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple nav menu with each item having 5 sub-items. I want the sub-itmes to be closed when the page loads. Only the first set is closed though when the page loads. 
Any feedback would be very helpful.  Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
$('#project').hide();   
$('h5').click( function(){          $(this).toggleClass('closed').next('#project').slideToggle().siblings('#project').slideUp();
    $(this).siblings('h5').removeClass('closed');
});                    
});

</script>
```

And here is part of the menu code:

```
 <div id="sidebar_nav">
  <h5>Education</h5>
    <p id="project">
    <a href="edu_project1.htm">project 1</a><br />
    <a href="edu_project2.htm">project 2</a><br />
    <a href="edu_project3.htm">project 3</a><br />
    <a href="edu_project4.htm">project 4</a><br />
    <a href="edu_project5.htm">project 5</a></p>
  <h5>Health Care</h5>
    <p id="project">
    <a href="hc_project1.htm">project 1</a><br />
    <a href="hc_project2.htm">project 2</a><br />
    <a href="hc_project3.htm">project 3</a><br />
    <a href="hc_project4.htm">project 4</a><br />
    <a href="hc_project5.htm">project 5</a></p>
  <h5>Housing</h5>
     <p id="project">
    <a href="hs_project1.htm">project 1</a><br />
    <a href="hs_project2.htm">project 2</a><br />
    <a href="hs_project3.htm">project 3</a><br />
    <a href="hs_project4.htm">project 4</a><br />
    <a href="hs_project5.htm">project 5</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have more than one element with the same id (project), which is not correct for HTML and make jQuery confuse.

I recommend changing project id with a special class, for instance, project-menu and then adapting your jQuery code to $('.project-menu').

Answer (score 0):

You should not have duplicate ids. Use a class instead, so you'll have `class="project"` instead `id="project"`.

If you really want to have duplicate ids, change your selectors
from

```
$('#project')...
```

To

```
$('[id="project"]')...
```

This is because `#id` only finds the first in the page (cause it assumes there's only one), but `[id='id']` searches all matches.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: It is never recommended to have duplicated ids.

Comment: That's exactly what I said in the first line. Please read more carefully.

Comment: I did it, and you say "If you really want to have duplicate ids...". This is never advisable and you are giving a workaround that jQuery's magic can handle, but it wouldn't.

Comment: I'm not advising it. I'm giving the information that _it's possible_. It's important to give this information. For example, if he didn't have control over the markup (i.e. html from 3rd party) to change it, using this technique would solve the problem. Or, if someone's traversing XML with jquery, could have an id attribute that could be repeated. I gave both choices cause someone with those constraints, or simply someone for which it's useful could be benefited from that code. I never advised, as it's _clear_ in my solution.

Comment: Ok, then, I removed my downvote. The phrase "If you really want to have duplicate ids" doesn't reflect what you now say. I think you should edit your answer adding all these possible situations and being very clear that duplicate ids is never wanted. Thanks for your explanation.